# как убрать внутреннюю часть круга?

Tags: python, turtle

как сделать так, чтобы внутренний круг был чистым?
пустым?
при том, что внешняя часть должна остаться. помогите пожалуйста[image: Сделать так] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import turtle
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.showturtle()
turtle.speed(12)
def kvadrat():
  for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
for i in range(100):
  kvadrat()
  turtle.left(5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Научитесь [поднимать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.up) и [опускать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.down) перо при движении черепашки:

```
import turtle


turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.showturtle()
turtle.speed(12)


def ugol():
    turtle.up()
    for i in range(4):
        if i == 1:
            turtle.down()
        if i == 3:
            turtle.up()
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.down()


for i in range(100):
    ugol()
    turtle.left(5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]